# Rails 2.3.x: Is it possible to call a controller's action from Initializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I am using rails 2.3.8 . I need to call a controllers action from a initializer.
I found this snippet in rails 3 usin Proc

```
    OmniAuth.config.on_failure = Proc.new do |env|
    UserSessionsController.action(:omniauth_failure).call(env)
    end
```

If i use this in Rails 2.3.8, it returns this error

```
   undefined method `action' for UserSessionsController:Class.
```

It seems Rails 2.3.8 does not have "action" method. 
Is there any other way to call an action from initializer in Rails 2.3.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this, but controllers are just classes. So something like

```
TestController.new.index
```

will call the `index` method.

Keep in mind that the controller will be initialized w/o all the info that normally comes in w/ a request, so its very possible that things will break.